# Run javascript in a partial view with MVC5 C# and Razor

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a small web app in MVC5 and C# using the Razor Engine. In my code, I have a main view, which is a index of a table, with some buttons. When I click one of the buttons a Bootstrap modal appears.

So far so good, but the problem is that I want to perform certain actions when buttons on the modal are clicked, but nothing happens.

This is the main view:

```
    <div id="editModal"></div>
    <a class="btn btn-default editPackage"t itle="Edit Package"><i class="icon-edit"></i></a>
    <h1>Package List</h1>

    <table class="table" id="packagesTable">
        <!-- Big ass table here :D -->
    </table>
```

This is how I show the modal, by using jQuery:

```
 //Show Edit Package modal
    $(".btn.btn-default.editPackage").click(function () {

        $.ajax({
            url: $(this).data('url'),
            type: 'GET',
            cache: false,
            success: function (result) {
                $('#editModal').html(result).find('.modal').modal({
                    show: true
                });
            }
        });
        return false; //prevent browser defualt behavior
    });
```

So far so good. Everything works fine. The problem comes with the modal ...

This is the modal:

```
<div class="modal fade in" id="editPackageModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="editPackages" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" style="overflow-y: auto; max-height: 90vh; height: 80vh;">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Edit Package MyPackage</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <form class="form-horizontal">
            <div class="control-group">
              <label class="control-label">Package Name:</label>
              <div class="controls">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="package-name" placeholder="MyPackageName">
              </div>
            </div>
            <!-- Other fields here -->
          </form>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="savePackageChangesBtn">Save changes</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

This is teh Javascript I wish to run when a button in the modal is clicked:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#savePackageChangesBtn").click(function() {
    $('.modal').modal({
      show: true
    });
    return false; //prevent browser defualt behavior
  });
});
```

The main view is in a file called "Index.cshtml". The modal view is a file called "_EditModal.cshtml" (because it is a partial view). The javascript code is a file called "custom.js", which is used and runs perfectly fine in the main view.

Why is this not working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your modal is added dynamically, but your `$("#savePackageChangesBtn").click(function()` is registered at DOM ready time (when the target element does not exists to bind on).

If you added `alert($("#savePackageChangesBtn").length);` before the click handler it would return 0.

Use a delegated event handler, attached to a non-changing ancestor element.

e.g.

```
$(document).on('click', "#savePackageChangesBtn", function()
```

This works by listening for the event to bubble up to a non-changing ancestor, then applies the jQuery selector *at event time* not *event registration time*. This means the element only needs to exists when the click occurs.

You would normally choose a non-changing element close to the loaded content, so probably use `#editModal` instead of document

e.g.

```
$('#editModal').on('click', "#savePackageChangesBtn", function()
```

Note: `document` is the best default if nothing else is convenient, but do not use `'body'` as styling can cause it to not respond to bubbled mouse events (e.g. if the calculated height of the `body` is zero).

Comment: is there another, easier way to show a modal and run javascipt on it? Or should I create another question?

Comment: @Flame_Phoenix: For the benefit of others using this site, separate questions make more sense. Thanks.

Comment: @GoneCoding You are a life saver. Thanks : )

Answer (score 1):

Either add `$("#savePackageChangesBtn").click(function() {});` code after  you show modal

e.g.

```
//Show Edit Package modal
$(".btn.btn-default.editPackage").click(function () {

    $.ajax({
        url: $(this).data('url'),
        type: 'GET',
        cache: false,
        success: function (result) {
            $('#editModal').html(result).find('.modal').modal({
                show: true
            });
            $("#savePackageChangesBtn").click(function () {
                $('.modal').modal({
                    show: true
                });
                return false; //prevent browser defualt behavior
            });
        }
    });
    return false; //prevent browser defualt behavior
});
```

Or Add the following to your document.ready

```
$(document).on("click", "#savePackageChangesBtn", doSomething);
```

This makes your document to listen to elements created after init.

And in doSomething add what you want.

Comment: Your first option is not a good pattern to follow in modern jQuery (that's why we have delegated events). :)

Comment: will create another question for that thanks ! Kudos++!